# Configure microk8s to use ~/.kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I've added stuff to my `~/.kube/config` which doesn't appear when I do:

```
microk8s.kubectl config view
```

I'd like to use Microk8s with the default config file location.

Is this possible?

Comment: I got the same problem and noticed that if you use kubectl from `snap install kubectl` it works as expected. In my case it doesn't work even when you set it in cmd line (as suggested by @Aghya Sadhy

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in the latest snap version (1.14.1) by editing /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubectl and changing --kubeconfig to point to your own preferred config file, or in my case:

--kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG}

Comment: As I wrote above this wan't enought in my case.
BTW: rel 1.20.1 doesn't accept `--kubeconfig ${KUBECONFIG}` and requires `--kubeconfig ${KUBECONFIG}`